# Test Web application on iOS Simulator

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

I am trying to optimize my website for iPad. Could you please guide me on the best approach:

1. In terms of whether I should separate desktop/ipad just by CSS or redirect to an entirely different domain (e.g. mysite.com/ipad)
2. How do I test on iPad simulator? Should I use XCode for development?

Please help me with some good online tutorials. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best to either use separate css files or just make a complete liquid layout,

as far as testing goes, you can download the ipad dev kit with xcode for the emulator

Comment: What exactly is ipad dev kit with xcode for the emulator ? I already have an $99 IOS developer account which I use for native development..so i have already installed the ios sdk? Is the ipad dev kit  separate download?

Comment: WHere and how do I find it installed?

Comment: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone\ Simulator

Comment: Thanks a lot for that..I opened the same and it opens an iPhone Simulator..How do I get an iPad simulator?

Comment: one of the menus on the top bar will allow you to select ipad if i remember rightly

Answer (score 5):

Once you are in iOS simulator, go to "Hardware > Device > iPad"

Answer (score 0):

This online iPad Simulator http://alexw.me/ipad2/ will allow you to test your page along with CSS3 and javascript.

Comment: Is this an accurate simulator. Have u used the same? I have heard that most iPhone/iPad simulators are just an iframe in that browser and do not give actual device simulation. Please confirm.

Comment: Yes. The "simulator" link provided above is just a web page within IFRAME. There are some services which provide screenshots taken on actual hardware devices like https://browshot.com/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Browshot.com](http://browshot.com/)? You can get free credits and try a few screenshots on the iPad browser. It uses an actual mobile browser.

Answer (score 0):

For **Windows** and **Linux** users who want to run `iOS` simulator inside `macOS` using `VirtualBox`.

**CURRENT SOFTWARE VERSIONS:**

1. MacOS 10.14 Mojave;
2. VirtualBox 5.2.22;
3. Xcode 10.

**REFERENCE:**

1. Guide: [How to Install macOS 10.14 Mojave on VirtualBox on Windows?](https://www.intoguide.com/install-macos-mojave-virtualbox-windows/).

**Prepare VirtualBox:**

1. [Download VirtualBox for your OS](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads);
2. [Download VirtualBox x.x.xx Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack (one for all OSs)](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads);
3. Install `VirtualBox` + `Extension Pack` (usually by double-clicking -> OS should recognize that `Extension Pack` must be opened by `VirtualBox`);
4. [Download VirtualBox's Virtual Disk with preinstalled MacOS 10.14 Mojave](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xERBkv1x1KSut37IN1oPS17it1QlDlHO)
5. Open `VirtualBox`;
6. Create a new Virtual Machine using `an existing virtual hard disk file`;
7. [TIP] Follow instructions in [Step 5. Customizing Virtual Machine’s Preferences](https://www.intoguide.com/install-macos-mojave-virtualbox-windows/) of the referenced guide, if you do not know how to configure Virtual Machine. The most important thing is to give MacOS at least 2 CPU cores;
8. We need to set some configurations. Replace `"Virtual Machine Name"` below by the name which you used in step 6 when you were creating Virtual Machine:

For `Windows` users we need to enter the next lines (line by line) in a command line:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\"
VBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Virtual Machine Name" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

For `Linux` users just create a file, for example `myscript`, with a content:

```
#!/bin/bash
VBoxManage modifyvm "Virtual Machine Name" --cpuidset 00000001 000106e5 00100800 0098e3fd bfebfbff
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemProduct" "iMac11,3"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiSystemVersion" "1.0"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/efi/0/Config/DmiBoardProduct" "Iloveapple"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/DeviceKey" "ourhardworkbythesewordsguardedpleasedontsteal(c)AppleComputerInc"
VBoxManage setextradata "Virtual Machine Name" "VBoxInternal/Devices/smc/0/Config/GetKeyFromRealSMC" 1
```

and run it in a terminal as `source ./myscript`.

**Install macOS 10.14 Mojave on VirtualBox** ([Step 7. Install macOS 10.14 Mojave on VirtualBox](https://www.intoguide.com/install-macos-mojave-virtualbox-windows/) from the guide):

1. Open VirtualBox and start the created Virtual Machine;
2. Wait for some seconds until the codes panel and apple logo go away;
3. On the Welcome screen, select your country and select continue;
4. Select your Keyboard layout;
5. Select, don’t transfer any information type and click continue;
6. Decide to sign in with Apple ID or Not;
7. Agree to the terms and conditions;
8. Create an Account for the macOS Mojave 10.14;
9. Choose a look for your Mac Device, whether it is the light mode or Dark Mode;
10. Select Continue on the Express Set up window;
11. Wait for Some seconds until your Mac is set up for use.

**Install iOS simulator:**

1. Install [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) (Click blue Download in the Top Right corner, provide your Apple ID and you will be redirected to `App Store`);
2. Open `Xcode` (from `App Store` or from `Finder -> Applications -> Xcode`);
3. Select `Get started with a playground` + `Blank` in order to skip all annoying steps.

**Test Site + Use Simulator:**

1. ==============

   1.1. Open `Xcode`;

   1.2. In the top menu select `Xcode -> Open Developer Tool -> Simulator`;

   1.3. [TIP] You can `Keep in Dock` Simulator, so you do not need to run `Xcode` every time;

   1.4. In the top menu select `Hardware -> Device` to select device/iOS for simulation;

   1.5. [TIP] In the top menu select `Hardware -> Manage Devices...` + `Simulators` tab to install a packages with other versions of iOS;

   1.6. Open your site in `Simulator's iOS Safari`;
2. ==============

   2.1. Open Desktop Safari;

   2.2. In the top menu select `Safari -> Preferences...` + `Advanced` tab -> Tick `Show Develop menu in menu bar`;

   2.3. In the top menu select `Develop -> SIMULATED DEVICE -> YOUR SITE`.