# iOS simulator for windows 7 to test websites

Tags: user-interface, ios-simulator, font-face, emulation, iso

I'm a UI Developer and I want to get an iOS simulator to test my work as I found later that some features don't work on iphone/ipad and the included custom fonts don't work as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test Web application on iPad Simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5535404/test-web-application-on-ipad-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

You can only use ios Simulator when you have an Xcode running on Intel based Mac Computer. I found this link interesting, i am not sure whether this works or not. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ipadian-ios-simulator-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running virtual box with a MacOSX install then as mentioned previously, open the contents of the XCODE directory and there is an iOS Simulator there.